# Passed arguments are not interpreted in curl command

Tags: bash, sh

I have a shell script that only does a curl command to notify my Discord server about an issue. I pass two arguments which I want to add into the data body of the curl command but their values are not interpreted.

My script call:

```
./notifier.sh usernameArg contentArg
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "$1", "content": "$2"}' "https://<discord webhook url>"
```

But all it sends is `{"username": "$1", "content": "$2"}`.
I also tried to use ${1} and ${2} with same result.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Variables are not expanded inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "'$1'", "content": "'$2'"}' "https://<discord webhook url>"
```